# Add significance asterisks to graph between multiple bars within each x-axis in ggplot bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, significance

I am trying to indicate which treatments are significantly different from the control within each of my x-axis labels in a `ggplot` bar graph.
I have Taxonomy as the x-axis and four different bars within each one indicating the experimental treatments and growth of each of these taxa for each treatment as the y-axis.

I attached a screenshot of a sample graph made using the code provided (with error bars eliminated from code) as well as some dummy data where "Y" indicates significance from control (feel free to make those numbers if that is easier).

I have tried using `geom_signif`, but it seems that I am unable to add more then one comparison within the same x-axis column indicating differences only between columns themselves.

I have also tried plotting a `geom_point` with values for each asterisk, but have not been able to align the asterisks with their respective treatment bars.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
ggplot(Experiment, aes(x=Taxa, y=Growth, fill=Treatment)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=0.5, color="black", position=position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colorsvalue, name = expression(paste(Treatment)), labels=leglabs, position="top")+
  ylab(expression( Growth~ (day^{-1})))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme (axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_discrete (labels = xlabs)+
  theme (axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, size=10))+
  theme(text = element_text(size=20))
```

**Graph**

[image]

**Sample data**

[image]

Comment: Hi Megan! What you want is an asterisk in the top of each bar showing the significance level?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your data using `dput(data)` rather than as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buried in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102486/12400385) is the trick of setting the width of `position_dodge` to 0.9 to align points with bars. Then you can add shape to your original `aes`, but set one shape to `NA` and one shape to be `8` (a star). Also you can add 1 in the `aes` of `geom_point`.

```
ggplot(Experiment, aes(x = Taxa, y = Growth, fill = Treatment, shape = star)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Growth + 1),
             position = position_dodge(0.9), 
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(NA, 8))
```

[image]

Data

```
structure(list(Taxa = c("Cyano", "Cyano", "Cyano", "Cyano", "Dolicho", 
"Dolicho", "Dolicho", "Dolicho", "Gompho", "Gompho", "Gompho", 
"Gompho", "Nosto", "Nosto", "Nosto", "Nosto"), Treatment = c("Control", 
"D. pulex", "D. magna", "0.25", "Control", "D. pulex", "D. magna", 
"0.25", "Control", "D. pulex", "D. magna", "0.25", "Control", 
"D. pulex", "D. magna", "0.25"), Growth = 2:17, star = c("", 
"Y", "Y", "", "", "Y", "Y", "Y", "", "", "", "Y", "", "", "", 
"Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

---

**EDIT**

An example with negative numbers, using an `ifelse` statment to either add 1 or subtract from the y location of the star.

```
ggplot(Experiment, aes(x=Taxa, y=Growth, fill=Treatment, shape = star)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_point(aes(y = ifelse(Growth > 0, Growth + 1, Growth - 1)),
             position=position_dodge(0.9), 
             show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(NA, 8))
```

[image]

Data with negatives

```
structure(list(Taxa = c("Cyano", "Cyano", "Cyano", "Cyano", "Dolicho", 
"Dolicho", "Dolicho", "Dolicho", "Gompho", "Gompho", "Gompho", 
"Gompho", "Nosto", "Nosto", "Nosto", "Nosto"), Treatment = c("Control", 
"D. pulex", "D. magna", "0.25", "Control", "D. pulex", "D. magna", 
"0.25", "Control", "D. pulex", "D. magna", "0.25", "Control", 
"D. pulex", "D. magna", "0.25"), Growth = -10:5, star = c("", 
"Y", "Y", "", "", "Y", "Y", "Y", "", "", "", "Y", "", "", "", 
"Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: This also worked, but I'll need to figure out how to add the stars to negative y-values.

Comment: Maybe you could do something like `y = ifelse(Growth > 0, Growth + 1, Growth - 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to plot the factors that contain 'Y' as an asterisk. You can do that by first calculating the location of each value as a new.x and offset with a new y value. You can adjust the new.y value to whatever suits your needs. Because you have four plots on each, the center of the bar is (0.25 + 0.5)/2 for the ends and (0.25 + 0)/2 for the middle bars. Negative is to the left of the bars. For reference I used the second example on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763876/how-to-combine-geom-bar-geom-point-and-geom-line-into-one-figure)

```
library(dplyr)
    Experiment <- Experiment %>% mutate(new.x = ifelse(Treatment == "0.25", -0.375, 
                                                ifelse(Treatment == "Control", -0.125, 
                                                ifelse(Treatment == "D. magna", 0.125, 0.375))) + 
                                                as.numeric(as.factor(Taxa)))
    Experiment$new.y <- Experiment$Growth +1
    
    ggplot(Experiment, aes(x=Taxa, y=Growth, fill=Treatment)) + 
      geom_col(size=0.5, color="black", position=position_dodge())+
      geom_point(data=subset(Experiment, Star == 'Y'), aes(x=new.x, y=new.y), shape=8, show.legend=FALSE) +
      #scale_fill_manual(values=colorsvalue, name = expression(paste(Treatment)), labels=leglabs, position="top")+
      ylab(expression( Growth~ (day^{-1})))+
      theme_classic()+
      theme (axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
      #scale_x_discrete (labels = xlabs)+
      theme (axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, size=10))+
      theme(text = element_text(size=20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think this will work. I will need to figure out how to also add asterisks if the y is negative. I could probably modify the new y in a similar manner where it is -1 when it is -Y.

I do have one question though, I looked at the link you provided for reference, but I am still unclear as to exactly what the numbers mean in those two equations; where is the 0.25 from (having four bares or four sets of bars?)